# Alternative to Dbus for communication between an application and gnome extension

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I have created a gnome extension which acts as a widget for my application. I want the Widget to update its content using the data from my application.

I have tried an extension for spotify app and it uses dbus interface to reflect the song played on the app. I have also found this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/dbus#:%7E:text=DBus%20is%20an%20inter-process%2Cto%20exchange%20data%20and%20commands.) which states that gnome extensions broadly utilizes dbus for communication.

I Wanted to know is there any alternative to communicate data between my application and my extension, and if there is a way, is it recommended?

Thanks.